# Problems with JavaScript typwriter and basics

Tags: javascript, html

```
var index = 0;
var text = 'Hello.';
function type()
{
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
    index += 1;
    var t = setTimeout('type()',50);
    document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML="<p>Hi</p>"; 
}
```

I am trying out this typewriter idea thing, but I want to print a sentence (not in the typewriter style) *after* the typewriter has done its thing. I'm sorry if it's a really basic problem, I'm just starting out with JavaScript.

Comment: Is your code supposed to be the definition of the `type()` function?

Comment: Sorry! typo... Should be fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var index = 0;

function typer() {
    var text = 'Hello';
    if (text.charAt(index) != '') {
        document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML = "<p>Hi</p>";
    }
    index++;
    var t = setTimeout('typer()', 100);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PjTm8/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to test whether you've reached the end of `text`:

```
function type() {
    if (index < text.length) {
        document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
        index++;
        setTimeout(type, 50);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML = '<p>Hi</p>';
    }
}
```

It's also preferable to supply a function, not a string, as the first argument to `setTimeout`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ZQaNC/3/)